# What was the first movie or show to use a conlang?

Tags: dialogue, first-appearance

**What was the first movie or show to use a conlang?**

---

Def: [Conlangs](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conlang): an invented language intended for human communication that has planned and cohesive phonological, grammatical, and syntactical systems. They can be [*a priori* languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructed_language)

I've listed a (very well known) few of them:

1. [Elvish](https://www.elfdict.com/) - The Lords of the Rings
2. [High Valyrian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valyrian_languages) and [Dothraki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dothraki_language) - Game of Thrones
3. [Klingon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klingon_language) - Star Trek
4. [Na'vi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Na%CA%BCvi_language) - Avatar
5. [Barsoomian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barsoomian_language) - John Carter

I'm not taking into account made-up languages like [parseltongue](https://sites.google.com/site/parseltongue101/lesson1) (Harry Potter) or [Mangani](https://whatsitsgalore.com/etc/tarmangani.html) (Tarzan) because they're intended to talk to/with animals and not interact with humans (or alike).

I'm not taking into account either some languages like [Nadsat](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:A_Clockwork_Orange) (A Clockwork Orange) or [Newspeak](http://www.orwelltoday.com/newspeak.shtml) (1984) because they derived from existing languages and/or slang words, and were not invented (from imagination) and constructed languages. These probably rank amongst the [anti-languages](https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20160211-the-secret-anti-languages-youre-not-supposed-to-know) like thieves' Cant, Polari, and Gobbledygook and [many others](https://listverse.com/2014/05/25/10-secret-outlaw-languages/).

To be as accurate as possible, **Huttese** (StarWars) (derived from Quechua, a native American language of the Andes region, and other Peruvian languages and it does have similarities with long-dead languages such as Mayan and Nahuatl (spoken by the Aztecs in Mexico)) or **Wakandan** (Wakanda Forever) (derived from [Xhosa and Nguni languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xhosa_language)) or similar languages should normally not qualify as conlangs too but I may be wrong, so please comment/correct if necessary.

As the moment, I've found no older than the [1974 TV series Land of the Lost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_of_the_Lost_(1974_TV_series)).

NOTE: conlangs have a long history, as earlier as [12th century Lingua Ignota](https://thelanguagecloset.com/2020/07/18/lingua-ignota-the-first-constructed-languages/), as well as in books. I'd like to focus on conlangs for M&TV but any reference to books is welcome. ie. *New Language (1909)* has been used in "*that wonderful movie you know and that no one never heard of*" (1946).

NOTE: from comment, to clarify the expected outcome for this question. I try to spot a *fantasy* language that was used in movie or tv show. It has to be an invented language, fully functional like the definition of the dictionary. It can be first invented for a book, then used in the movie, or directly created for the movie. As examples, Elvish would qualify (1st in a book in 1954, then in a [movie in 1978](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptations_of_The_Lord_of_the_Rings) then 2001) but Esperanto (1887) would not qualify, as it's intended to be a universal second language for international communication.

Comment: @ToddWilcox : thanks for pointing out. I clarified, is it better now?

Comment: Yes, I think that will help get you the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

### [The Last Laugh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Laugh_(1924_film)) 1924

A silent movie but the signs in the film are believed to be in [Esperanto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto), or, if they aren't, they are in an unknown constructed language.

Comment: thanks for the hint. Any chance you show us a screenshot or picture of these signs? Are they fingerspelling (because of the silent movie) or just pictures/book shown on screen?

Comment: You can watch the whole thing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W7yiZM-SlwI

Comment: that's a poison apple :)) but thanks, I'll go throught it when I have time

Comment: Interesting. The only Esperanto movie I'd heard of is the 1966 movie Incubus with William Shatner.

Comment: I don't think it is Esperanto. Wikipedia only lists "etali" and "farina" as examples of alleged Esperanto words, but Google Translate doesn't know either, nor do they appear in [this dictionary](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/16967). Besides that it says "Alfred Hitchcock took [it] as Esperanto", but I don't think he knew Esperanto. @OldPadawan "etali" and "farina" can be seen at [27:58](https://youtu.be/W7yiZM-SlwI?t=1678). The other signs in that shot appear to say "vhist cigarettes" and "Atlantic".